Navigation issue in Swiftui iOS 18 skipping a page
I have an app that takes an ObservableObject known as AppState(), sets up as StateObject and is passed through to MenuView() and so on as an EnvironmentObject from the @main struct.
My MenuView makes use of the new TabView with TabSection and Tab. This is nested in a NavigationStack with navigationDestination() inside it and .alert() attached to the outside of it.
The primary use case for this attached Alert is to navigate to a specific page from ANY view within the app.
ContentView() navigates to PageTwo() by use of navigationDestination() which binds to an @EnvironmentObject updated within a Task  (the actual app performs async operations, so this needs to be kept). Note that NavigationStack is also in this view and not the others.
On PageTwo(), navigating to PageThree() navigate the same way as before but will also start a timer for 10 seconds.
Once the timer is up, an alert will popup. This gives the option to navigate to the ThirdPage() again. This seems to work well from any View inside the app.
The issue I am running into though is, once navigation to PageThree() has occurred VIA THE ALERT, pressing the Back button in the top left will skip PageTwo() and go straight back to ContentView().
Undesired behaviour.
Is there something I am doing wrong? Am I setting up the navigation incorrectly? Have I handled the navigationDestinations incorrectly?
Min repro:
@main
struct FirstAppApp: App {
    
    @StateObject private var app = AppState()
    
    var body: some Scene {
        WindowGroup {
            MenuView()
                .environmentObject(app)
        }
    }
}

struct MenuView: View {
    
    @EnvironmentObject var app: AppState
    @State private var device = UIDevice.current.userInterfaceIdiom
    @AppStorage("MyAppTabViewCustomization")
    private var customisation: TabViewCustomization
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationStack {
            Group {
                if app.showDisclaimer {
                    Legal()
                } else {
                    TabView {
                        ForEach(SidebarItem.allCases, id: \.self) { tab in
                            TabSection("Planning") {
                                Tab("Plan", systemImage: "house") {
                                    ContentView()
                                }.customizationID("plan")
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    .tabViewStyle(.sidebarAdaptable)
                    .tabViewCustomization($customisation)
                }
            }
            .navigationDestination(isPresented: $app.atisUpdated) {
                PageThree()
            }
        }
        .alert(isPresented: $app.newAtisAvailable) {
            Alert(
                title: Text("Press GO to navigate to page 3"),
                primaryButton: .default(Text("GO"), action: {
                    Task {
                        app.atisUpdated = true
                    }
                }),
                secondaryButton: .cancel(Text("STOP"), action: {
                    Task {
                        app.atisTimer.invalidate()
                    }
                })
            )
        }
    }
}

enum SidebarItem: String, Identifiable, CaseIterable {
    case planner = "Planner"
    var id: String { self.rawValue }
    var iconName: String {
        switch self {
        case .planner:
            return "house"
        }
    }
    var customizationID: String {
        switch self {
        case .planner:
            return "planner"
        }
    }
}


struct ContentView: View {
    
    @EnvironmentObject var app: AppState
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationStack {
            VStack {
                Text("Page 1")
                Button("Go to page 2") {
                    Task {
                        app.readyToNavigate = true
                    }
                }
            }
            .navigationDestination(isPresented: $app.readyToNavigate) {
                PageTwo()
            }
        }
    }
}


struct PageTwo: View {
    @EnvironmentObject var app: AppState
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text("Page 2")
            Button("Go to page 3") {
                Task {
                    app.atisButtonPressed = true
                    await app.startTimer()
                }
            }
        }
        .navigationDestination(isPresented: $app.atisButtonPressed) {
            PageThree()
        }
    }
}


struct PageThree: View {
    @EnvironmentObject var app: AppState
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationStack {
            VStack {
                Text("Page 3")
            }
        }
    }
}



class AppState: ObservableObject {
    @Published var showDisclaimer: Bool = false // !UserDefaults.standard.bool(forKey: "DisclaimerAccepted")
    @Published var atisButtonPressed: Bool = false
    @Published var readyToNavigate: Bool = false
    @Published var atisUpdated: Bool = false
    @Published var atisTimer: Timer = Timer()
    @Published var newAtisAvailable: Bool = false

    @MainActor
    func startTimer() async {
        self.atisTimer = Timer.scheduledTimer(withTimeInterval: 10, repeats: true) { _ in
            self.newAtisAvailable = true
        }
    }
}


The issue is because you have multiple NavigationStack.
You could try to remove them all except the one in ContentView (works for me).
Note, there is no need for all your Task{...} in the Buttons,
remove them, except in PageTwo.

I just tried this but it doesn't seem to work. I get: "Do not put a navigation destination modifier inside a "lazy” container, like List or LazyVStack." purple warning because the .navigationDestination is outside a NavigationStack.

remove of course the  .navigationDestination(isPresented: $app.atisUpdated) { PageThree() } in the MenuView. I'm sure you can find a solution, rather than wait for someone else to do it for you.

Try replacing class AppState with @State

@workingdogsupportUkraine I just don’t have a great understanding of it. I thought someone with better knowledge than myself might be able to see the issue I’m not seeing. I have moved it all around so many times trying to get it. It seems the nav happens only between the View the .navigationDestination is pinned to and the destination View. With that in mind, been trying different Navstacks etc. https://forums.developer.apple.com/forums/thread/756647 this says navstack in each view

The issue is because you have multiple NavigationStack.
If you need more control over the path of the NavigationStack
try using NavigationStack(path: $navigationPath) { ....} and
change the path in your Views accordingly.
Here is my example code that works for me.
struct MenuView: View {
    @EnvironmentObject var app: AppState
    
    @State private var device = UIDevice.current.userInterfaceIdiom
    @AppStorage("MyAppTabViewCustomization")
    private var customisation: TabViewCustomization
    
    var body: some View {
        Group {
            if app.showDisclaimer {
                Legal()
            } else {
                TabView {
                    ForEach(SidebarItem.allCases, id: \.self) { tab in
                        TabSection("Planning") {
                            Tab("Plan", systemImage: "house") {
                                ContentView()
                            }.customizationID("plan")
                        }
                    }
                }
                .tabViewStyle(.sidebarAdaptable)
                .tabViewCustomization($customisation)
            }
        }
        .alert(isPresented: $app.newAtisAvailable) {
            Alert(
                title: Text("Press GO to navigate to page 3"),
                primaryButton: .default(Text("GO"), action: {
                    app.atisUpdated = true
                }),
                secondaryButton: .cancel(Text("STOP"), action: {
                    app.atisTimer.invalidate()
                })
            )
        }
    }
}

struct ContentView: View {
    @EnvironmentObject var app: AppState
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationStack {
            VStack {
                Text("Page 1")
                Button("Go to page 2") {
                    app.readyToNavigate = true
                }
            }
            .navigationDestination(isPresented: $app.readyToNavigate) {
                PageTwo()
            }
        }
    }
}


struct PageTwo: View {
    @EnvironmentObject var app: AppState
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text("Page 2")
            Button("Go to page 3") {
                Task {
                    app.atisButtonPressed = true
                    await app.startTimer()
                }
            }
        }
        .navigationDestination(isPresented: $app.atisButtonPressed) {
            PageThree()
        }
    }
}


struct PageThree: View {
    @EnvironmentObject var app: AppState
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text("Page 3")
        }
    }
}

struct Legal: View {
    var body: some View {
        Text("Legal")
    }
}

Note, the forums link you show in your comment does not say ...navstack in each view,
it says NavigationStack for each Tab (that needs it). The meaning is
NavigationStack should not be the top most View, it/they should be inside the TabView. Note also, you will have to adjust your .alert(...) code as I don't really understand what you want to achieve with it.
EDIT-1:
An alternative approach is to use NavigationStack(path: $app.path) {...} as
shown in this example code:
struct MenuView: View {
    @EnvironmentObject var app: AppState
    
    @State private var device = UIDevice.current.userInterfaceIdiom
    @AppStorage("MyAppTabViewCustomization")
    private var customisation: TabViewCustomization
    
    var body: some View {
        Group {
            if app.showDisclaimer {
                Legal()
            } else {
                TabView {
                    ForEach(SidebarItem.allCases, id: \.self) { tab in
                        TabSection("Planning") {
                            Tab("Plan", systemImage: "house") {
                                ContentView()
                            }.customizationID("plan")
                        }
                    }
                }
                .tabViewStyle(.sidebarAdaptable)
                .tabViewCustomization($customisation)
            }
        }
        .alert(isPresented: $app.newAtisAvailable) {
            Alert(
                title: Text("Press GO to navigate to page 3"),
                primaryButton: .default(Text("GO"), action: {
                    app.atisUpdated = true
                    app.path.append("Page3")  // <--- here
                }),
                secondaryButton: .cancel(Text("STOP"), action: {
                    app.atisTimer.invalidate()
                })
            )
        }
    }
}

struct ContentView: View {
    @EnvironmentObject var app: AppState
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationStack(path: $app.path) {  // <--- here
            VStack {
                Text("Page 1")
                Button("Go to page 2") {
                    app.readyToNavigate = true
                    app.path.append("Page2")  // <--- here
                }
            }
            .navigationDestination(for: String.self) { page in  // <--- here
                if page == "Page2" {
                    PageTwo()
                } else if page == "Page3" {
                    PageThree()
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

struct PageTwo: View {
    @EnvironmentObject var app: AppState
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text("Page 2")
            Button("Go to page 3") {
                app.atisButtonPressed = true
                app.path.append("Page3")  // <--- here
                Task {
                    await app.startTimer()
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

struct PageThree: View {
    @EnvironmentObject var app: AppState
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text("Page 3")
        }
    }
}

struct Legal: View {
    var body: some View {
        Text("Legal")
    }
}

class AppState: ObservableObject {
    @Published var showDisclaimer: Bool = false // !UserDefaults.standard.bool(forKey: "DisclaimerAccepted")
    @Published var atisButtonPressed: Bool = false
    @Published var readyToNavigate: Bool = false
    @Published var atisUpdated: Bool = false
    @Published var atisTimer: Timer = Timer()
    @Published var newAtisAvailable: Bool = false
    
    @Published var path = NavigationPath() // <--- here
    
    @MainActor
    func startTimer() async {
        self.atisTimer = Timer.scheduledTimer(withTimeInterval: 5, repeats: true) { _ in
            self.newAtisAvailable = true
        }
    }
}


Thank you @workingdog support Ukraine, your version with the path works well! I do appreciate your answers, always easy to follow and helpful.

I think the problem is that you'r not ensuring that NavStack maintains the correct  state, the root cause is that the navigation state might be overwritten or improperly managed when the alert triggers the navigation.

You must ensure single NavStack in the entire App rather than nesting NavStacks instances within individual views, then Use Binding and ObservableObject properly, you must manage the navigation state more effectively by ensuring state changes are correctly bound and observed across views.

here is an update of your version code : 

import SwiftUI

@main
struct FirstAppApp: App {
    @StateObject private var app = AppState()

    var body: some Scene {
        WindowGroup {
            NavigationStack {
                MenuView()
                    .environmentObject(app)
            }
        }
    }
}

struct MenuView: View {
    @EnvironmentObject var app: AppState
    @AppStorage("MyAppTabViewCustomization") private var customisation: TabViewCustomization

    var body: some View {
        Group {
            if app.showDisclaimer {
                Legal()
            } else {
                TabView {
                    ForEach(SidebarItem.allCases, id: \.self) { tab in
                        TabSection("Planning") {
                            Tab("Plan", systemImage: "house") {
                                ContentView()
                            }.customizationID("plan")
                        }
                    }
                }
                .tabViewStyle(.sidebarAdaptable)
                .tabViewCustomization($customisation)
                .alert(isPresented: $app.newAtisAvailable) {
                    Alert(
                        title: Text("Press GO to navigate to page 3"),
                        primaryButton: .default(Text("GO"), action: {
                            app.atisUpdated = true
                        }),
                        secondaryButton: .cancel(Text("STOP"), action: {
                            app.atisTimer.invalidate()
                        })
                    )
                }
            }
        }
        .navigationDestination(isPresented: $app.atisUpdated) {
            PageThree()
        }
    }
}

struct ContentView: View {
    @EnvironmentObject var app: AppState

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text("Page 1")
            Button("Go to page 2") {
                app.readyToNavigate = true
            }
        }
        .navigationDestination(isPresented: $app.readyToNavigate) {
            PageTwo()
        }
    }
}

struct PageTwo: View {
    @EnvironmentObject var app: AppState

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text("Page 2")
            Button("Go to page 3") {
                app.atisButtonPressed = true
                app.startTimer()
            }
        }
        .navigationDestination(isPresented: $app.atisButtonPressed) {
            PageThree()
        }
    }
}

struct PageThree: View {
    @EnvironmentObject var app: AppState

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text("Page 3")
        }
    }
}

class AppState: ObservableObject {
    @Published var showDisclaimer: Bool = false // !UserDefaults.standard.bool(forKey: "DisclaimerAccepted")
    @Published var atisButtonPressed: Bool = false
    @Published var readyToNavigate: Bool = false
    @Published var atisUpdated: Bool = false
    @Published var atisTimer: Timer = Timer()
    @Published var newAtisAvailable: Bool = false

    func startTimer() {
        self.atisTimer = Timer.scheduledTimer(withTimeInterval: 10, repeats: false) { _ in
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                self.newAtisAvailable = true
            }
        }
    }
}


This is not feasible if your app uses a TabView. Each Tab is expected to have its own NavigationStack.
